# How can I iterate a coordinate sphere using an expanding spherical sector (cone)?

Tags: c++, loops, graph, 3d, linear-algebra

Given an *integer* 3D coordinate system, a center point **P**, a vector in some direction **V**, and a max sphere radius **R**:

I want to iterate over only **integer points** in a fashion that starts at **P** and goes along direction **V** until reaching the max radius **R**.

Then, for some small angle **T** iterate all points within the cone (or spherical sector) around **V**.

Incrementally expand **T** until T is pi/2 radians and every point within the sphere has been iterated.

I need to do this with O(1) space complexity. So the order of the points can't be precomputed/sorted but must result naturally from some math.

[image: Sphere with expanding spherical sector]

Example:

```
// Vector3 represents coordinates x, y, z
// where (typically) x is left/right, y is up/down, z is depth
Vector3 center = Vector3(0, 0, 0); // could be anything
Vector3 direction = Vector3(0, 100, 0); // could be anything
int radius = 4;
double piHalf = acos(0.0); // half of pi

std::queue<Vector3> list;
for (double angle = 0; angle < piHalf; angle+= .1)
{
    int x = // confusion begins here
    int y = // ..
    int z = // ..
    list.push(Vector3(x, y, z));
}
```

*See picture for this example*

The first coordinates that should be caught are:

- A(0,0,0), C(0,1,0), D(0,2,0), E(0,3,0), B(0,4,0)

Then, expanding the angle somewhat (**orange cone**):

- K(-1,0,3), X(1,0,3), (0,1,3), (0,-1,3)

Expanding the angle a bit more (**green cone**):

- F(1,1,3), (-1,-1,3), (1,-1,3) (-1,1,3)

My guess for what would be next is:

- L(1,0,2), (-1,0,2), (0,1,2), (0,-1,2)
- *M(2,0,3) would be hit somewhat after*

[image]

Extra notes and observations:

- A cone will hit a *max* of four points at its base, if the vector is perpendicular to an axis and originates at an integer point. It may also hit points along the cone wall depending on the angle
- I am trying to do this in c++
- I am aware of how to check whether a point X is within any given cone or spherical vector by comparing the angle between V and PX with T and am currently using this knowledge for a lesser solution.
- This is not a homework question, I am working on a 3D video game~

Comment: Please provide an [mre] of your best attempt. Surely you have a program which represents the input data "Given an integer 3D coordinate system, a center point P, a vector in some direction V, and a max sphere radius R" in suitable data structures. Then, since you ask about "iterate", please demonstrate a single step of that iteration, i.e. the body of the innermost loop. Then an answer can help with constructing the loops and the math to derive the current values of the variables for your step. That way you can focus this question on the actual specific prgramming problem you encountered.

Comment: This question keeps coming up today. You didn't address the previous question: There's an infinity of points. A 3-dimensional infinity. Do you only want integer points ?

Comment: @Jeffrey, please elaborate "This question keeps coming up today." Is this a duplicate? Has this user asked a similar question already? Can you link? Do you suspect a homework assignment?

Comment: @Yunnosch this was deleted yearlier on. It was the same question, just even less clear (to me) and 2D. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344611/find-all-the-coordinates-inside-a-circle

Comment: There are similarities. But it is a different user and the question has been deleted. I do not see how you intend your comment to be helpful. @Jeffrey.

Comment: @Yunnosch: My intent is for OP to specify what "points" are to them. Integer coordinates point seems the most likely. But without this information, the question will get certainly closed.

Comment: Sorry guys about the confusion. I did mean only integer points (I realize now that writing integer coordinate system is not the right way of specifying that). Also, this is not a homework question, I am working on a 3D game.
@Yunnosch I will work on creating an example now~

Comment: @Jeffrey Thank you guys for your feedback. I hope I have addressed your concerns about my question and would appreciate if we could reopen it?

Comment: A reopen requires multiple votes. But if it gets reopen, my answer would now be: scan all the point in 3D (3 nested for's). for each point, compute the angle and distance. Insert the Vector3 into a multimap<float angle, Vector3 point> if the distance is within the sphere. Iterate over the multimap from lower_bound(0) to upper_bound(T). That will give you the point in the order you want.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks for that solution and for the explanation on reopening. I'm actually looking for an O(1) space complexity solution, which I realize now I should have specified. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Mike, the O(1) space requirement has me puzzled. I tried getting an answer there: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129183

Comment: the cone is cone or cone with spherical cap? what about points on cap are they wanted too ? You do not want points inside cone? its odd to have just points on axis and surface without cap ....

Answer (score 0):

1. **iterate all integer positions `Q` in your sphere**

   simple 3x nested `for` loops through `x,y,z` in range `<P-R,P+R>` will do. Just check inside sphere so

   ```
   u=(x,y,z)-P;
   dot(u,u) <= R*R
   ```
2. **test if point `Q` is exactly on `V`**

   simply by checking angle between `PQ` and `V` by dot product:

   ```
   u = Q-P
   u = u/|u|
   v = V/|V|
   if (dot(u,v)==1) point Q is on V
   ```
3. **test if points is exactly on surface of "cone"**

   simply by checking angle between `PQ` and `V` by dot product:

   ```
   u = Q-P
   u = u/|u|
   v = V/|V|
   if (dot(u,v)==cos(T/2)) point Q is on "cone"
   ```

   where I assume `T` is full "cone" angle not the half one.

Beware you need to use `floats/double` for this and make the comparison with some margin for error like:

```
if (fabs(dot(u,v)-1.0     )<1e-6) point Q is on V
if (fabs(dot(u,v)-cos(T/2))<1e-6) point Q is on "cone"
```